# Do multiple wilcoxon tests of drug sensitivity between mutated grp and wild-type grp need multiple testing correction?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am doing wilcoxon-rank-sum tests of the sensitivity (AUC) of over 1000 drugs between mutated gene A and wild-type gene A.

So, for each drug, there will be one wilcoxon test and one p-value. Since I have 1000 drugs, there will be 1000 tests and 1000 p-values.
And then, I am putting all the p-values gained from each individual tests (y-axis) into a volcano plot with x-axis being the effect size of AUC between mutated gene A and wild-type gene A.

I am wondering if I should plot the volcano with the p-values adjusted by multiple testing correction like Benjamini-Hochberg (BH) procedure. I found that some paper do this correction, while do not. So, this is making me confused if I should do the correction.

Answer (score 1):

The issues of how you display the volcano plot and how you make "significance" claims on the data are different.

Provided that you are clear about which method you use, you can display the volcano plot either way. As the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure controls false discovery rates, not family-wise error rate, if you choose to display the B-H values you can avoid some confusion by reporting them as [q-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Definitions). If a referee disagrees, it won't be hard to switch to the other display.

That said, you should not make statements about statistical significance on the uncorrected p-values. For this type of study, statements about positive findings are typically made with respect to false-discovery rates.

Comment: I am thinking each test actually has an independent hypothesis. 

hypothesis of test 1: drug 1 is more significantly sensitive to mutated gene A and wild-type gene A
hypothesis of test 2: drug 2 is more significantly sensitive to mutated gene A and wild-type gene A
....

it can come out that several drugs are significantly more sensitive to mutated gene A than wild-type gene A. So, why multiple testing correction should be done to compare the significance between all of these individual hypothesis.

Comment: I have several drugs of the same class that are significantly more sensitive to mutated gene A than wild-type gene A when p-values are uncorrected. But they are no longer significant after BH correction (FDR 5%). so in this case, I cannot report that this class of drug shows higher sensitivity to mutated gene A, right?

I am not sure if my thought is correct. Please correct me if I misunderstand it.

Comment: @Idiotsum the [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) is that if you do 1000 tests at p < 0.05, you expect to get about 50 positive results just by chance even if there are no real differences. That's what you need to protect yourself and your audience from by multiple comparison corrections.

Comment: @Idiotsum there might be ways to take into account sensitivities of _drug classes_ with respect to gene mutation status more efficiently, but that would require a different type of analysis. For example, you could use a mixed model, with the drug classes as a fixed effects and the individual drugs as random effects within their corresponding classes. Then your individual hypotheses are about the drug classes rather than the individual drugs, with much less of a multiple-comparisons problem.

Comment: Do u mean I could use a mixed model: drug sensitivity (AUC) ~  class of drug (fixed effect) + gene A mutation status + individual drugs within corresponding classes of drug (random effect)
to see if gene A mutation is a significant covariate affecting AUC?

Comment: Btw, I saw a paper using linear mixed effects models to test for differences in AUC for each compound dependent on gene X status. Fixed effects (gene X status) and random effects (replicate screen for each cell line). Then, a volcano plot was made with the uncorrected p-values from individual test of each compound (y-axis) with difference in mean AUC between mutated gene X and wild-type gene X as x-axis. The paper concluded that compounds with uncorrected p-values <0.05 are more significantly more sensitive to gene X mutation.

Comment: (continue with the above comment) According to our earlier discussion, do u agree that it may be more appropriate to use adjusted p-values after multiple testing correction?
(I am not sure if it is appropriate to cite the paper here, so I just describe it without citation.
Let me know if any part is unclear and need more elaboration. )

Comment: @Idiotsum I'm not sure that AUC is the best measure of outcome but, yes, the principle of using drug class as a predictor along with individual drugs nested within classes could work. How well it will work and whether to do nesting as fixed or random effects depends on things like number of drugs per class, disparity of drug effects within a class, etc. The most reliable reports account for multiple correction. If you report false-discovery rates (probably best for this type of study), refrain from using terms like "significance" that have specific frequentist implications.

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable advise! I'm gonna give it a try with the mixed effect model. 

I have one extra question about the FDR. If it is Anova test for the drug sensitivity (e.g. AUC ~ gene A mutation status + tissue types), when i do multiple testing correction for 1000 drugs, should I include the all the pvalues of gene A mutation status only or include those of both gene A mutation status and tissue types from all individual anova tests? (if I only wanna see the effect of gene A mutation status on drug sensitivity with tissue types as covariate)

Comment: @Idiotsum if you model individual drugs as random effects within drug classes, then you are down to many fewer than 1000 comparisons, as your major comparisons are among drug _classes_, not the individual drugs. The comparisons to correct for multiplicity are those on which you want to do inference. If you are treating tissue types simply as covariates and don't care about the differences among them you don't need to include them in the list of p-values to adjust.

Comment: What do u think of an acceptable FDR? I hv seen mostly 5%, but can also be up to 20%. Under what circumstances, is a higher FDR (20%) acceptable, like hving a large pool of tests (several hundreds to a thousand)?

Comment: @Idiotsum that depends on what you--and your potential audience--is willing to accept as a false-positive rate. For example, in a screen for drugs that might work best with a particular genotype, how many dead-end leads are you willing to risk when you move on to the next phase of the study to validate the initial hits in more detailed experimental studies? The higher the FDR, the more time and resources you will end up wasting on false-positive screen hits. I don't know of any general rule for an "acceptable" FDR.